# Download response as text file in silverlight

Tags: c#, json, wcf, silverlight

I am using a Silverlight application and the application accessing one of the endpoint in a WCF service and the output data format is in string  [ as a json file]

Now what i have to do is serve the data as JSON file to end user [ as a text file ]  How can i do this

Currently i am calling my wcf service like this

```
webservice.get_Export_ClassWiseCompleted += new EventHandler<get_Export_ClassWiseCompletedEventArgs>(webservice_get_Export_ClassWiseCompleted);

webservice.get_Export_ClassWiseAsync(class_id); //call wcf service async


void webservice_get_Export_ClassWiseCompleted(object sender, get_Export_ClassWiseCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.Error.InnerException.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            string response_data = (string)e.Result; //write this  data to text file
                     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("file.txt"); 
                    writer.WriteLine(response_data);
                    writer.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NO result");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Write the JSON string to a file?  You should be able to do something like `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("file"); writer.WriteLine(response_data); writer.Close;` I would expect.

Comment: I am getting error file operation not permitted..

Comment: Show the code where you're getting the error.  We can't help you without more information.

Comment: @Tim code edited and getting exception @ initialization of STreamWriter with filename

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons silverlight will not let you save without a save file dialog because it is executing in a sandbox.

```
void webservice_get_Export_ClassWiseCompleted(object sender, get_Export_ClassWiseCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Error != null) {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.Error.InnerException.Message);
    } else {
        if (e.Result != null) {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() {
                DefaultExt = "txt",
                Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files(*.*)|*.*",
                FilterIndex = 1,
                DefaultFileName = "file"
            };
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true) {
                string response_data = (string)e.Result; //write this  data to text file
                using(Stream stream = sfd.OpenFile()) {
                    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) { 
                        writer.Write(response_data);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("NO result");
        }
    }
}
```